# open-ended note for serial downvoter, will that help?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

Few minutes back, I received [serial down votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2015-08-05%2008:01:32Z) to all my questions.

I am not at all worried abut the votes as I know they will get reversed thr' the script, most probably by midnight today, if not sooner.

I assume, this is the *result* of a comment and close-vote on one of the recent questions. The problem is, I can't seem to find the question anymore (deleted, maybe)? My intent was to post another comment saying something like

> @seraildownvoter: downvoting mine (or anyone else's) questions won't help you get your problem solved. Furthermore, if you continue this behaviour, you're likely to face some harsh decisions as per the community rule. Instead, try to [edit] and improve your question. If you need any help other than the links already provided, please leave a comment for clarification.

I'm not trying to target anyone specific, just trying to help someone relatively new (I assume) here, who is not particularly familiar with how *things* work here. Maybe I can add a link to a meta post reading the serial-voting issue, too. This way if the new member corrects him/herself, he/she can probably avoid the warning message from a mod this time and in future. Also, they will be aware of the community rules.

So, my question is two-folded

1. Shall I do that?
2. If yes, in this case, how?

Let me know your views.

Comment: AFAIK only mods can know who downvoted a question. You can only assume OP did it. If you choose the wrong question, you may send that comment to an innocent.

Comment: Hmya, you know what caused it, you didn't *have* to post that snarky comment.   If you don't like the consequences of Newton's third law then just don't apply force, that question would have been closed anyway.

Comment: @SergeBallesta sir, that is why i thought of using that seemingly invalid `@serialdownvoter` tag. :-) Nevermind, point taken. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant Agree. Was not trying to have a conversation over there, really, just a thought like this came to mind, so tried to validate. Who knows, if the Q was not deleted, I might have actually posted this comment. So, for my own self, I thought of getting it clarified. :-)

Comment: Offtopic: I think the DV's this question is getting shows the disagreement to this proposal, right? Or is there anything else fundamentally wrong with this question? Anyone, thoughts?

Comment: @SergeBallesta for the record, mods cannot see who downvoted a question.  Only people with full database access (which is limited to SE employees, specifically the developers and community team).  Mods can see patterns in voting that would suggest whether there was serial voting, but they can't see specific votes.

Comment: The down votes here are almost certainly disagreement. Honestly, even if the down voter were to see your comment I don't think it would matter. While there are certainly things that a user would only learn through the Help Center or experience on the site, I don't think users need to be *told* that serial down voting is an unfair thing to do.

Comment: Hah, i'm tired of this . One more time today....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Shall I do that?

No. It is noise, and you'll often find the serial-downvoter will downvote and run, never returning to check your posts, so your comment will never get read.

> This way if the new member corrects him/herself, he/she can probably avoid the warning message from a mod this time and in future.

A warning from a moderator isn't worse than a warning from yourself. Our first contact with a user is almost always both a warning and educational anyway, rather than a straight out suspension. I therefore can't see much gained here by you contacting them rather than us; except that our message *will* reach the user, where as your open-ended note only *might*.

Comment: _"except that our message will reach the user, where as your open-ended note only might."_. That cleared everthing. Thanks. :-)